# Problem with writing simplified commands

Tags: syntax

I would like to know how I can learn to write a complicated command with syntax like the one below. I might know each one separately, but I can not combine them or know the pattern which works for example where to apply `@*`, `MatchQ[{(a_) ..}]` or `@*MatchQ[{(a_) ..}] @*`.

```
Select[Not @* MatchQ[{(a_) ..}] @* Differences] @ test
```

Comment: `@*` means composition, while `@` is shorthand for `Prefix`. `f@x` is just `f[x]`, while `(f@*g)[x]` is `f[g[x]]`

Comment: Have you seen [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/106) by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)?

Comment: Build the solution up step-by-step in separate cells so you can examine the intermediate results. After each step and the sequence of steps is working correctly, start combining the steps one at a time until you finally have the one-line solution. After you have done this several times you will be able to skip several or all of the intermediate steps.